# Capture guard-rspec output to use in other files

Tags: ruby, json, rspec, guard

I am trying to create a program using ruby and [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to watch `.rb` files in a directory for changes, then on change I would like to run a set of Rspec specs and capture the results of the specs.

I have it set up to watch the appropriate files, run the specs, and output the spec results as a json string into the guard terminal. How can I capture that json string to analyze in another ruby file?

Guardfile:

```
guard :rspec, :cli => "--format json" do
  watch(%r{^*\.rb}) { "spec" }
end
```

Comment: Are you wanting to capture all Guard output or just the JSON?

Comment: I just want to capture the JSON string that holds the rspec results.

Comment: If you're running it pragmatically with ruby store it in a variable and write it out. If you're doing it with a system command, just use the file feed thing `command < the_file`.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: edit: Posted the Guardfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guard :rspec, :cli => "--format json < ./tmp/spec_results.json" do
  watch(%r{^*\.rb}) { "spec" }
end
```